# reading external xml file and making it available to the JavaScript running on the same environment

Tags: c#, .net

I ran into some problems using jQuery to read an external xml file and build a tree. To get around it, I am working on C# code to read the external xml file and present the data to the jQuery. Here is my code so far:

I would like to read the external xml file and print it out as is. Can someone help me how to print the xml file as is?

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" %>  
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>  

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  

<script runat="server">  
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)   
  {   
        string xmlFile = "http://192.168.101.1/img/jstree.xml";   
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();   
        settings.IgnoreComments = true;   
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;   
        Console.WriteLine(xmlFile); 
       try   
        {   
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile, settings))   
            {   
                string xmlContent;   
                while (reader.Read())   
                {   
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)   
                    {   
                        xmlContent = "";   
                        if (reader.Name == "root")   
                        {   
                            xmlContent += "<root>" + "<br />" "reader.ReadString().ToString() + "<br />";   
                        }   
                        if (reader.Name == "item id")   
                        {   
                            xmlContent += reader.ReadString().ToString() + "<br />";   
                        }   

                        if (reader.Name == "content")   
                        {   
                            xmlContent += reader.ReadString().ToString() + "<br />";   
                        }   

                         if (reader.Name == "name")   
                        {   
                            xmlContent += reader.ReadString().ToString() + "<br />";   
                        }   
                        Label1.Text += xmlContent;   
                    }   
                }   
            }   
        }   
        catch (Exception ex)   
        {   
            Label1.Text = "An Error Occured: " + ex.Message;   
        }   
    }   
</script>  

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >  
<head id="Head1" runat="server">  
    <title>XmlReader: How to read and process Xml file element data in asp.net</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <div>  
             <asp:Label    
             ID="Label1"  
             runat="server"  
             Font-Bold="false"  
             ForeColor="Crimson"  
             Font-Size="Large"  
             Font-Names="Comic Sans MS"  
             >  
        </asp:Label>  
    </div>  
    </form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Can someone help with how do I read this jstree.xml and present it to the jQuery. In jQuery, I should be able to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#div").jstree({
        "xml_data": {
            "ajax": { 
                "url": "jstree.xml"
```

Comment: try pass "url" :"jstree.aspx", jstree.aspx should be a script that will read the XML and will return it as Response.

Comment: I like to be able to read the external xml file and write the output to the console in c#, how I do that?

Comment: @Alberto Leon, I have update the code. I can read the external file and would like to print out the xml file as an xml file in original format. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery should request to ASP.NET Page, like "jstree.aspx", this page, jstree.aspx, should return a XML Stream.

In your ASPX, after the code you writed:

> ```
>     Response.Clear();
>     Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
>     Response.Charset = "utf-8";
>
>     XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
>     settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
>     settings.Indent = true;
>     using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Request.OutputStream, settings))
>     { 
>        //Write here
>     }
> ```

Comment: Leon, I am very sory very new to c# as you can see. I am not following your answer. Can you be clear?